# Why don't the servers use 7z?

Tags: compression, 7z

By default on a UNIX machine install, I can see the logs are rotated with gzip.

**Question:** Why doesn't the UNIX world use by default 7z? It would be much more efficient than gzip..

I just compressed a directory with many HTML files.

7z: 1,8 MByte

zip: 440 MByte

Comment: There was some discussion here on the topic http://superuser.com/questions/205223/pros-and-cons-of-bzip-vs-gzip

Comment: 7z isn't installed by default on most UNIX (Solaris, HP-UX or AIX) - you have to get it separately on those, the vendors don't package it. I'm not even sure it's installed by default on most Linux distributions.

Answer (score 5):

Archiving (grouping files in a single entity) and compressing are usually done in separate steps under Unix.

That gives more flexibility when you want to manipulate single files (that wouldn't benefit from archiving) — think pipelines such as `gzip -cd mylog.gz | grep '^Oct.*error'`.  Achieving the same with `7z` would be awkward.¹

`7z` (and `zip`, and `rar`, and `arj`, and...) are archivers that happen to compress.  They wouldn't replace traditional `gzip` as they do not have the same purpose.

`gzip` is fast, light on resources, very well-known and installed on most Unix systems.  If you're looking for a higher-performance compressor, go for `xz`.  It offers a command line interface very similar to `gzip` but uses more or less the same LZMA algorithms as `7z` so you should get similar compression ratios.

---

1) The above pipeline is so common that many wrappers exist around `gzip` tools; a seasoned user would probably opt for `zgrep '^Oct.*error' mylog.gz` to save a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

With logrotate, log files can be compressed only one file at a time (that's a limitation, and not really a problem in practice, IMHO), and `gzip` is used by default, most probably for historical reasons and it has not changed yet. You can still use another compressor with the `compresscmd` command. See the logrotate(8) man page for more information.

In the future, logrotate might have a different default. I suppose that the best compressor nowadays is `xz`, but it's still rather new.

If you use different log rotation software, see its documentation.